# How to integrate Braintree with xamarin android

Tags: java, c#, android, .net, xamarin

I tried to integrate braintree payment gateway with my xamarin android project,
But got many problems on that.

Can anyone please help me to integrate the Braintree payment gateway in Android.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android and https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/android-payforum :

Comment: yes @MadhukarHebbar but i need help on xamarin.android not on java android code... thanks